# Is it correct to declare types/attributes in an interface from OOP point of view?

Tags: oop, interface, abap

Is it correct to define a type within an interface? And what about an attribute?

Some programming languages only allow method signatures for an interface, but in ABAP I was considering doing something like the code below, even adding more attributes, and I'm not sure if the approach is a correct OOdesign:

```
INTERFACE zif_notif_note.
  TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_note_id,
           notif_num    TYPE qmnum,
           activity_key TYPE aknum,
         END OF ty_note_id.
  DATA: id TYPE ty_note_id READ-ONLY.
  METHODS get_id
    RETURNING VALUE(r_id) TYPE ty_note_id.
 ENDINTERFACE.
```

What if I need to use this type as an input parameter for another class? Should I better define DDIC structure then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your first question: nothing speaks against defining a type in an interface.

To your second question...

You can do many things in ABAP OO that you cannot do in other object oriented languages like Java or C++. For example you can define a `FINAL ABSTRACT CLASS` which is nonsense, you can define static methods (`CLASS-METHODS`) in an interface which is in my opinion a heresy towards the object oriented programming.

I have never defined attributes unless they were `CONSTANTS` within an interface, because there is no reason for doing it. They will be automatically marked as `PUBLIC` which breaks in fact the encapsulation principle.

So the answer would be: It is possible but think twice before going that way because it might be breaking the encapsulation of the classes that implement the interface.

Comment: "can do many things in ABAP OO that you cannot do in other..." I would have said "can do many things in other... that you cannot do in ABAP OO" ;-) About attributes, I don't see any issue to define them as `READ-ONLY` in interfaces, to avoid to define so many setters and getters. As I tend to have almost one interface per class, it permits to simplify a lot my code.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add the READ-ONLY in the example above (edited now). But I also use this technique to avoid writing getters.

Comment: Regarding the question. Maybe I should extend that I may need a method from another class that needs the type defined in the interface as input parameter, so then I'm using an interface type as before I was using DDIC structure, and I'm not sure if this is coupling too much.

Comment: Is your interface a local interface or a global one (defined in SE24)?

Comment: It's a global interface

Comment: `nothing speaks against defining a type in an interface` nothing except SAP recommendations. Clean code guidelines [do not recommend](https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/blob/master/clean-abap/CleanABAP.md#prefer-enumeration-classes-to-constants-interfaces) declaring constants in interfaces, I believe the same logic applies to types

Comment: There is `DEFINITION PUBLIC ABSTRACT FINAL` in those guidelines, so tell me more... Abstract final is a heresy from the point of view of object orientation.